# Clonar carpeta de mi rama de GIT en Path Especifico

Tags: git

Me gustaría saber si es posible clonar una carpeta que esta en mi rama, en una carpeta especifica fuera de donde se hace el pull.
Tengo un proyecto de laravel y me gustaría que al hacer pull de git solo la carpeta "public" se clonara en una carpeta especifica.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitarás al menos Git 2.24

```
git clone \
  --depth 1 \
  --filter=combine:blob:none+tree:0 \
  --no-checkout \
  "file://$(pwd)/repo" \
  local_repo \
;
cd local_repo
git checkout master -- public/
```

`depth` hará que solo bajes master sin historial. `no-checkout` evita que bajes ningún fichero en la carpeta. `filter=blob:none` evita que bajes blobs en el `.git` y `tree:0` hace lo mismo para el árbol

Y con el checkout final te bajas la carpeta